# Change Gridview row backcolor if two cells have a certain value/color

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and I want to change the color on page load of multiple rows if one of the header cells has a backcolor of red and if one of the cells in that column has a tick in it (the tick is a html image).

the code I have so far is

```
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    y = 3

    For m = 0 To availableRuns.Rows.Count - 1
        If availableRuns.HeaderRow.Cells(y).BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E95B4D") Then
            If row.Cells(y).Text = "<img src='images/green_tick.png' />" Then
                availableRuns.Rows(m).BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E95B4D")
            End If

        End If

    Next
```

But this changes all the rows to red.  Looking at the image below I need to change all the rows to red for GT2 except 2 and 8.

[image: Gridview Example2]

Can anyone help?  Using MS VS 2013, VB.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it after thinking about it over the weekend.  I changed my IF statement to the following.

```
            For m = 0 To availableRuns.Rows.Count - 1

            If availableRuns.HeaderRow.Cells(y).BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E95B4D") And availableRuns.Rows(m).Cells(y).Text = "<img src='images/green_tick.png' />" Then
                availableRuns.Rows(m).BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E95B4D")
            End If

        Next
```